matching pattern in an audio signal using normalized cross correlation

The image shows an audio signal of a 16Hz wave file. We have to search for an orange pattern in green.
The result should be the correct index, which is the 7th index of green where orange is getting repeated and a similarity factor. Although the pattern is changing over time, I think still there is a possibility of identifying it using a similarity factor.
I have tried many solutions such as cosine similarity, euclidean distance, fft etc. but still not able to find a solution that can identify the pattern. Here is the code using normalized cross-correlation:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.signal

orange = np.array([-0.67788696,  0.35198975,  0.69580078, -0.02264404, -0.24002075,
        0.33798218,  0.40097046, -0.03103638,  0.22860718, -0.21273804,
       -0.3649292 , -0.19015503, -0.2906189 , -0.01010132,  0.03689575,
       -0.15289307, -0.14328003, -0.50906372, -0.57232666])
       
green = np.array([-0.69995117, -0.58444214, -0.07501221,  0.1862793 , -0.03338623,
        0.05426025, -0.40628052, -0.543396  ,  0.17922974,  0.52752686,
        0.61419678,  0.00531006, -0.027771  ,  0.12228394,  0.13223267,
        0.69995117, -0.13153076,  0.05752563, -0.32174683, -0.19555664,
       -0.52252197, -0.59085083, -0.16491699,  0.1791687 , -0.05090332,
       -0.03591919, -0.45037842, -0.5687561 ])       
       
def normalized_cross_correlation(signal1:np.ndarray, signal2:np.ndarray):
    """
    Calculate the normalized cross-correlation between two signals.

    Parameters:
        signal1 (ndarray): First signal.
        signal2 (ndarray): Second signal.

    Returns:
        ndarray: Normalized cross-correlation between the two signals.
    """
    # Check if the signals have zero variance
    if np.std(signal1) == 0 or np.std(signal2) == 0:
        return np.nan

    # Normalize both signals
    signal1_normalized = (signal1 - np.mean(signal1)) / np.std(signal1)
    signal2_normalized = (signal2 - np.mean(signal2)) / np.std(signal2)
    
    # Calculate the cross-correlation between the two normalized signals
    cross_correlation = np.correlate(signal1_normalized, signal2_normalized, mode='full')
    
    # Normalize the cross-correlation
    cross_correlation /= np.sqrt(np.sum(signal1_normalized**2) * np.sum(signal2_normalized**2))
    
    return cross_correlation

def find_best_match(signal1:np.ndarray, signal2:np.ndarray):
    """
    Find the best match between two signals using normalized cross-correlation.

    Parameters:
        signal1 (ndarray): First signal (pattern to search for).
        signal2 (ndarray): Second signal (the signal being searched).

    Returns:
        float: Similarity score between 0.0 and 1.0 (1.0 indicating a perfect match).
        int: Index of the best match in the second signal.
    """

    # Calculate normalized cross-correlation
    cross_correlation = normalized_cross_correlation(signal1, signal2)
    
    # Return zero similarity score and invalid index
    if np.any(np.isnan(cross_correlation)):
        return 0.0, -1 
    
    # Find the index of the peak in the cross-correlation
    best_match_index = np.argmax(cross_correlation)
    
    # Calculate the similarity score
    similarity_score = cross_correlation[best_match_index]
    
    return similarity_score, best_match_index
    
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6), dpi=80)
gs = fig.add_gridspec(2, hspace=0)
axs = gs.subplots()    
axs[0].axhline(y = 0.0, color = 'lightgray', linestyle = '-', linewidth=1.0) 

# Get the difference
diff = len(green) - len(orange)

ss = []
bmi = []
for loop in range(0, diff):
    # keep shifting orange on green index by index
    similarity_score, best_match_index = find_best_match(orange, green[loop:len(orange)+loop])
    if best_match_index != -1:
        ss.append(similarity_score)
        bmi.append(best_match_index)
    
# Find the max score
score = max(ss)
best_match_index = bmi[ss.index(score)]
print (score, ss.index(score), best_match_index)

axs[0].plot(orange, color='orange')
axs[1].plot(green, color='green')
axs[1].plot(7, green[7], '.', color='black', markersize=15)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
plt.close() 
exit()

The code is not producing the correct index which is 7. What would be the ideal solution here for pattern matching?

Update the normalized_cross_correlation function to calculate the cross-correlation using the more appropriate mode (not full) and interpret the results to find the correct starting index for the pattern in the green signal without redundant looping. Here's an updated version that searches for the waveform and finds it at index 7
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.signal

orange = np.array([-0.67788696,  0.35198975,  0.69580078, -0.02264404, -0.24002075,
        0.33798218,  0.40097046, -0.03103638,  0.22860718, -0.21273804,
       -0.3649292 , -0.19015503, -0.2906189 , -0.01010132,  0.03689575,
       -0.15289307, -0.14328003, -0.50906372, -0.57232666])
       
green = np.array([-0.69995117, -0.58444214, -0.07501221,  0.1862793 , -0.03338623,
        0.05426025, -0.40628052, -0.543396  ,  0.17922974,  0.52752686,
        0.61419678,  0.00531006, -0.027771  ,  0.12228394,  0.13223267,
        0.69995117, -0.13153076,  0.05752563, -0.32174683, -0.19555664,
       -0.52252197, -0.59085083, -0.16491699,  0.1791687 , -0.05090332,
       -0.03591919, -0.45037842, -0.5687561 ])       
       

def normalized_cross_correlation(signal1:np.ndarray, signal2:np.ndarray):
    """
    Calculate the normalized cross-correlation between two signals.
    """
    if np.std(signal1) == 0 or np.std(signal2) == 0:
        return np.nan

    signal1_normalized = (signal1 - np.mean(signal1)) / np.std(signal1)
    signal2_normalized = (signal2 - np.mean(signal2)) / np.std(signal2)
    
    cross_correlation = np.correlate(signal2_normalized, signal1_normalized, mode='valid')
    
    cross_correlation /= np.sqrt(np.sum(signal1_normalized**2) * np.sum(signal2_normalized**2))
    
    return cross_correlation

cross_correlation = normalized_cross_correlation(orange, green)

# Find the index of the peak in the cross-correlation
best_match_index = np.argmax(cross_correlation)

# Calculate the similarity score
similarity_score = cross_correlation[best_match_index]
similarity_score, best_match_index

output:
(0.3894741869827266, 7)


I was doing exactly the same way as you have suggested but it was not working that's when I started testing it index wise. The reason for failure is too much deformation in the pattern over time.
